# How to change list of booleans to incremental numbers

Tags: python

Is there a way to change boolean values in a list to incremental values based on certain conditions?

I have these two variables:

```
answers = [True, True, False, True, True, False, False]
p = 2
```

This is my code:

```
[x-p if x == False else x+x for x in answers]
```

This is the output (which is incorrect):

```
[2, 2, -2, 2, 2, -2, -2]
```

This is the desired output:

```
[1, 2, -2, 4, 5, -2, -2]
```

I know why this is happening as `True == 1` in integer terms so essentially it sees `1+1`, but I don't know how to make it add incrementally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line gives you the right output :

```
[i+1 if answers[i] == True else -2 for i in range(len(answers))]
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works. I hate myself for not being able to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
answers = [True, True, False, True, True, False, False]
output = [i if answer else -2 for i, answer in enumerate(answers, 1)]
print(output) # [1, 2, -2, 4, 5, -2, -2]
```

Comment: I tried an approach similar to this, but my order was mixed up. List comprehension isn't very intuitive.

Comment: List comprehensions will always preserve order though, so that shouldn't be an issue. Did you maybe try to change the list you were iterating over?

Comment: This is definitely the most Pythonic answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest:

```
[i+1 if x else -2 for i,x in enumerate(answers) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking for. With your given set of variables

```
 answers = [True, True, False, True, True, False, False]
 p = 2

 retval = []
 temp = 0

 for item in answers:
     if item:
        item += temp
        retval.append(item)
     else:
        retval.append(item-2)
     temp += 1

# retval is the output list with [1, 2, -2, 4, 5, -2, -2]
```

Let me know in case you have any questions regarding the above.